# change php curl to json response

Tags: php, json

currently I have a php file that returns the data to the client via curl,  I have changed the client to respond to JSON, to handle a problem and all works great.  But now is it possible to return the data as JSON object.  It currently Returns alot of html tags etc that I am not interested in,I would like to return just the raw text as an example the text is in this format C5:3;

Below is the code would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

```
//set POST variables
  $url = $_POST['url'];
  unset($_POST['url']);
  $fields_string = "";
  //url-ify the data for the POST
  foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
   $fields_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
   }
  rtrim($fields_string,"&");
   //open connection
   $ch = curl_init();
   //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
   $url .= '&';
   $url .= $fields_string;
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   //execute post

   $string = curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);
```

I am looking to return a JSON object like this,

```
$data = array('success'=> true,'message'=>'C5;3');
```

This is the client code.

```
     $("button.checkStatus").click(function(){
            //This Ajax checks the current on/off status of the passed X10 code            
            $('img.checkStatus').each(function(i, obj) {
                var element = $(this);
                $x10Device = $(this).data("x10");
                var postData = "url=http://192.168.0.34:81/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&f=DeviceStatus&d=" + $x10Device ; 



 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: postData,
    beforeSend: function(x) {
        if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
            x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        }
    },
    url: 'urlencodeJson.php',
    success: function(data) {
        // 'data' is a JSON object which we can access directly.
        if (data.success == true){
            $('#section1').html(data.message);
            //$("x10").data('src','lightbulbon.png');
             element.attr('src','lightbulbon.png');
    }
        else{
            $('#section2').html(data.message);     
             element.attr('src','lightbulbon.png');
        }
    }
   });
```

Comment: what is the response you get back?

Comment: Let's see some of the code at the target page `$url`. If I understand you correctly, that's where you need to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain"); //if html elements exists in array, it will echo as plain text

$yourarray = array('success'=> true,'message'=>'C5;3');

echo json_encode($yourarray);
?>
```

Comment: LOL, I would've suggested that but his question wasn't clear. He said he gets a bunch of html tags back but then shows an array.

Comment: This what I am doing at the client side of things.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple to do it just use simple_html_dom it a very powerful PHP class that u can parse html from PHP and get result after getting curl result u can do some thing like that

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
  unset($_POST['url']);
  $fields_string = "";
  //url-ify the data for the POST
  foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
   $fields_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
   }
  rtrim($fields_string,"&");
   //open connection
   $ch = curl_init();
   //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
   $url .= '&';
   $url .= $fields_string;
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   //execute post

   $string = curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);
   require 'simple_html_dom.php';
   $html= new simple_html_dom();
  $html->load( $string );
  foreach($html->find('div#selector') as $article) {
$article['title']=$article->find('div#title',0)->plaintext;
$article['photo']=$article->find('img#id',0)->atrr('id');
$article['content']=$article->find('div#content',0)->plaintext;
}
```

u have a php array();
u can convert to json array() php `json_encode()`
to see more example visit convert [curl result to JSON](http://zrclassroom.com/toturials/convertir-curlresultat-a-un-tableau-json-partie-01-246)